# Tag cleanup: Delete the [bug-report] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) tag doesn't specify any cohesive topic. Instead, there are questions under this tag about:

- how to report bugs to developers;
- issues caused by specific bugs, whether identified by the user or reported by someone else;
- setting up bug-tracking software; and
- general hardware or software issues.

Can someone get rid of this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bug-report](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug-report) tag has been removed from all questions where it was previously used.